# Maximum upload size for file is not working

Tags: files

I have set file filed with 25MB Maximum upload size. But when i upload more then 25mb file it is uploading. How to stop this.Can we create any custom module for file size.

Comment: Check server max upload size (max_file_uploads).

Comment: put phpinfo(); in some where and check how much is your server max upload

Comment: can we set it by file_validate_size in custom module?

Comment: Only if your server supports it, that is when your field's allowed file size is lower than server's `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, as @Rupesh already told you (with slight error in parameter's name).

Comment: Using **setting.php** OR **.htaccess** you can achieve this :
In **setting.php :** ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M'); OR
In **.htaccess file : ** php_value upload_max_filesize 8M and php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
check this [link](https://drupal.org/node/109994#comment-189497)

Comment: @inizio Both can be blocked by webserver's admin in apache.conf, but other than that it seems a good answer. Why don't you post it as an answer? Just keep in mind it might fail, and that `post_max_size` may need updating, too.

Comment: Now I have changed these values in settings.php
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
and in my .htacces
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
But there is an new issue come,file field is disappeared and there is one error message
An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (10 MB) that this server supports.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 7 you can achieve by using **.htaccess**

- In your .htaccess file:

  - php_value post_max_size 8M
  - php_value upload_max_filesize 8M

  Check this [link](https://drupal.org/node/109994#comment-189497) for more information

Comment: Custom file validate function will **not** allow larger files if PHP will not permit uploading them in thee first place, so only your second paragraph is valid.

Comment: @Mołot I have updated my answer, thanks for clarification :)

Comment: As of PHP5.3 the first method here (settings.php) is no longer valid. In fact, it's never been valid. `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` have never been able to be overridden by `ini_set()`

Comment: @Clive I have updated my answer, thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Below module helps admin or user with similar admin privileges to change file upload limit on a website without changing php.ini file & restarting the server.

https://www.drupal.org/project/change_file_upload_limit