# How to increase the maximum upload size?

Tags: 7, files

I'd like to increase the maximum upload size from 2MB to 5MB on my website (I'm using WAMP). My first attempt to do this was to set `Content types > MY CONTENT TYPE > Manage fields > MY IMAGE FIELD > Maximum upload size` to `5 MB`, but that didn't work. Next, (after reading [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/113212/maximum-upload-size-for-file-is-not-working) and [this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/97193)) I added

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '5M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5M');
```

to my `sites/default/settings.php` file, but that didn't solve the problem either.

What am I doing wrong? Why didn't my first approach work?

Comment: Just to confirm, did you restart the server

Comment: @wolverine: Yes, I did.

Comment: @wolverine `ini_set` is 'on-the-fly' config...it wouldn't require a server restart. But, `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), so you can't override them with `ini_set()`. It needs to be done in .htaccess/php.ini. Or, more accurately, _"Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)"_

Comment: @clive I didn't know that, I used to do my config directly in php.ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your **php.ini** file for **Post max size** and **upload max size**

Just follow this link for reference , [Click here](http://codekarate.com/blog/drupal-7-increase-max-file-upload-size)

Comment: @Jeron
If it is not there then you can create one yourself on server. Create a php.ini file on the root of your server and follow the instruction on the mentioned link. Let me know for more queries

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has been asked a year back but still I make my answer below to benefit someone who is in need because I had the similar kind of issue which I resolved by changing in ".htaccess" file.

```
# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
...
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M
...
</IfModule>
```

Just add the above 2 lines (phpvalue) in .htaccess file and you are done!

Thanks to the [Increase upload size in your php.ini](https://www.drupal.org/node/97193) where I finally got the solution.